# Asynchronous API Request by Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two files foo.js and foo.html.

In foo.js i take information from a API (i suppose its asynchronous) and foo.html has access to that object.

```
  <tr data-ng-repeat="y in vm.apidata">
                                    <td>{{y.name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{y.is_closed}}</td>
                                </tr>
```

But here i can't see anything. *There is no mistake with codes to show that and i take information as array of objects.*

I take information from API properly but vm.apidata is not initialized so that i can show it in foo.html.

How can i ensure that it has been shown?

Comment: Declare `vm` like `var vm = {};vm.apidata=[]`

Comment: Can we see the javascript for your controller

Comment: Remember that if your asynchronous data retrieval code is outside of the Angular loop, you have to specifically call scope.$digest/$apply to alert Angular to trigger dirty checking for changes. Angular controls the the entire reflow of the UI and might not be aware of changes introduced by external non-Angular JavaScript.

Comment: @cbayram, i'm looking for $apply but i'm not sure how i can implement it in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Aqsan, I'll write this up in an answer as it'll be too verbose for the comments.

My hypothesis is that you have to call $scope.$digest/$apply() upon your external code completing its task or perhaps as soon as the **scope** object of interests, vm.apidata, is mutated.

IMPORTANT: Angular is expecting vm.apidata to be an scope object. Simply putting in the global window/self scope is not what your markup is referencing.

window.vm.apidata != scope.vm.apidata

If indeed you are correctly updating the scope node, you can use the same scope reference to call scope.$apply().

However if you aren't below is some info.
Read more about [Scopes](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

You can inject references to the **$rootScope**, which is the top level root scope in your *services*(provider, factory), *controllers* and *directives*.  Similarly *$scope* of hierarchical interest is relevant in *controllers* and *directives* and can be injected there thus Scope objects are inherited (cascade down) in a parent-child hierarchy with the exception of isolated scopes which can be implemented in custom directives or in the case of ng-repeat directive for example. I'm going to give you a skeleton for a Controller (for simplicity sake) implementation where you might put implement the connection:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

// This is a Service
// observe how you inject the root scope
// the array wrapper around the factory is for JS code minification protection which might name your parameter to something shorter and make it invalid (AngularJS-wise)
myModule.factory('retrieveService', ['$rootScope', '$q', function($rootScope, $q) {
  function retrieve(){

    // perhaps return a promise using the injected (light-weight) angular $q service
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    // Your external code can go in here for retrieval
    // When your async code complete call for success
    deferred.resolve(<yourapidata>);

    // alternatively for error
    deferred.reject(<yourerror>);

    // of course you could also just set the value to the $rootScope.vm.apidata here and call $apply
    $rootScope.vm.apidata = <yourapidata>;
    $rootScope.$apply();


    return deferred.promise;

  }
  return retrieve;
  }]);

// This is a Controller
myModule.controller('MyCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'retrieveService', '$q', function(rootScope, $scope, retrieveSvc, $q) {

  function retrieve(){
    // Your external code could go in here inside the controller too
    // upon async retrieval perhaps...
    $scope.vm.apidata = <yourvalue>
  }
  // given you take care of your async call using promises and/or callbacks
  retrieveService().then(function(apidata) {
    $scope.vm.apidata = apidata;
    // though $scope is recommended imho, alternatively
    // you could bind the vm.apidata to $rootScope (here or in your service) as well which $scope will inherit
    $rootScope.vm.apidata = apidata;
  });

}])
```

There is much to learn/expand on and the permutations are vast, but hopefully this gives you a good general direction. [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) angular service might be a good option depending on your backend api.

Comment: I have solved it, not in this way precisely but again using by $scope. After $scope.apidata take a asynchronous return from api, $scope.$apply has been done. Then i could see the returned data in my ui. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for $apply() and/or $watch -- an example thread might be this one [AngularJS $location.path(path) not updating at first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255714/angularjs-location-pathpath-not-updating-at-first/20259345#20259345)

Comment: I'm a newbie and example you gave in hat topic seems to me so complex that i can't figure it out in this case actually